# Parsing nested JSON with Alamofire 4

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, wordpress-rest-api

So I have been trying all day to parse JSON from my WordPress REST API using Alomofire 4, I have tried everything I could find that is/was related to my issue yet I still can't manage to fix my issue.

The goal is just to do a request from the API and print it out, from there I can manage but since the JSON seems to be having nested arrays/dictionaries I have a hard time figuring out what to use.

My Code:

```
Alamofire.request(_newsURL).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result)

        if let json = response.result.value as? [Any] {

            print("JSON: \(json)")
        }

        if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

            print(response.result.value)

            if let slug = dict["slug"] as? String {

                self._newsSlug = slug
            }

            print("Hello News")
            print(self._newsURL)
            print(self._newsSlug)
        } else {
            print("Found Nothing")
        }
    }
```

The API: http://www.wsvh.nl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

My goal is to simply call and print out stuff such as the title (which is btw also nested even more?). I was trying to get it work with just the slug since that I not as nested as the rendered title, so I figured I should begin with the most simple part but I can't even manage to get that to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API returns an ***array of dictionaries*** where each dictionary represents a *Post* of type `[String: Any]`:

```
Alamofire.request(_newsURL).responseJSON { response in
  if let posts = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
    posts.forEach { post in
      if let slug = post["slug"] as? String {
        print("Slug: \(slug)")
      }
      if let title = post["title"] as? [String: String] {
        print("Title: \(title["rendered"])")
      }
      if let categories = post["categories"] as? [Int] {
        print("Categories: \(categories)")
      }
      // You can retrieve as many field as you like as above...
    }
  }
}
```

I strongly recommend you making use of an object mapping library such as [`ObjectMapper`](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) so you don't have to worry about type checking or casting at all.

Just create a model named `Post`:

```
import ObjectMapper

class Post: Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {

  var title: String?
  var slug: String?

  var link: URL?
  var content: String?

  required init?(map: Map) {}

  func mapping(map: Map) {
    title <- map["title.rendered"]
    slug <- map["slug"]

    link <- (map["link"], URLTransform())
    content <- map["content.rendered"]
  }

  var description: String {
    return "Post <\(title ?? "No title")>"
  }
}
```

so you can retrieve all posts as follows:

```
import AlamofireObjectMapper

Alamofire.request("http://www.wsvh.nl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
  .responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Post]>) in

    // This will give you the array of Post objects.
    print("Posts: \(response.result.value)")
}
```

I've created an [example project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5k332m2zcq2wqvb/AAAgb6MUm6P2x0u6dHvjAtZta?dl=0) for you. You can download and play around with it to have a better understanding about how mapping is performed.

Comment: Finally it prints out the requests! However, my final goal is to make this into a tableview, so I will need to make the Title a var so I can use it to manipulate text. But trying to make Title into a var gives me and error cause it's not a String.

Comment: Holy moly! Thank you so much :D This totally solves all my problems, you saved me of the biggest headache ever.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of task I would suggest you to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It will help you to keep things simple and clean.
e.g.

```
    Alamofire.request(_newsURL).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value) //Don't forget to import SwiftyJSON
            debugPrint(json)
            debugPrint(json[0]["slug"].stringValue) //print value of slug property
            debugPrint(json[0]["title"]["rendered"].stringValue) //print nested value of title
        }
    })
```

Comment: Oh wow this works really well! I was just wondering, what would I have to do to make the title a var so I can work with it to manipulate the TableView?